# How can i read pdf with itext?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Now i have error: May 08, 2018 12:27:47 PM toUnicode

> WARNING: No Unicode mapping for CID+88 (88) in font
>   404198E5f54TimesNewRoman

And empty result.
If it will need I can give a file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please describe mor ein detail what you have done when you saw the error message.

Comment: @werner And also mention the version of iText that is used, because text extraction was improved over the last couple of years. Some errors that occured with iText 5.0.0 no longer occur with iText 7.1.2.

Comment: drive.google.com/file/d/1T906GnzJcoPHr-wO5v2Mvd9fGncOueVm/… i agree use any version of itext. itext not give warning. it only give empty result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample PDF does not contain the information required for text extraction.

The document uses subset fonts with ad-hoc encodings: The first glyph of the respective font used on a page is encoded by some start value `n`, the next used, different glyph by `n+1`, the next used, different glyph by `n+2`,...

E.g.
[image]
is hexadecimally encoded as `000a 000b 000c 000d 000e 000f 0010` for the first word and `0011 0012 0013 000c 000d 0010 0014 0015 0016` for the second word plus the colon. You can recognize the codes `000c`, `000d`, and `0010` in the second word corresponding to glyphs that already have been used in the first word.

Obviously this encoding without any extra information does not allow text extraction, how should a program map those values to Unicode?

The PDF format does have options to include a map from those encoding values to Unicode but unfortunately the fonts in your file don't include such mappings.

Thus, your file does not allow text extraction, you need to use OCR instead.

Comment: In other words: my answer was correct, and mkl was able to prove this once you shared the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

A PDF with text contains syntax that draws glyphs on a page. The shapes of these glyphs are stored in a font. The syntax used for the page uses characters to refer to the glyphs.

For instance:

```
12334 54637
```

Is a possible representation of:

```
Hello World
```

Where you have the following mapping:

```
`1` = `H`
`2` = `e`
`3` = `l`
`4` = `0`
` ` = ` `
`5` = `W`
`6` = `r`
`7` = `d`
```

When you look at the page as a human, you see "Hello World", but when a machine looks at the syntax of the page, it sees "12334 54637" and that's also what you get if you extract the content without using a `toUnicode` mapping.

The mapping that I just described ( `1` = `H`, `2` = `e`, `3` = `l`,...) is stored in an object that maps characters used in a page with Unicode characters. If that map is missing, there is no way of extracting the content correctly.

The error you mention *No Unicode mapping for CID+88 (88) in font 404198E5f54TimesNewRoman* informs you that information is missing in your PDF, hence you can't get a reliable result. You can see the correct text with your human eyes, but a machine can't resolve the text to a useful string.

If this answer doesn't satisfy you, please share the PDF so that we can prove that this answer is correct. Also: you don't mention which version of iText you're using. Older versions are usually not that good at extracting text when compared to the more recent versions (iText 7.1.2 being the most recent release).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T906GnzJcoPHr-wO5v2Mvd9fGncOueVm/view?usp=sharing                                                               i agree use any version of itext. itext not give warning. it only give empty result

Comment: See the answer by @mkl: my explanation was exactly the problem you're experiencing. The PDF is created in a way that doesn't allow text extraction.

Comment: You have to put your link to the file in the question itself, not in a comment below an answer.