# Not correct display of Russian characters after parsing pdf iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net, itext

I am trying to get data from a table in a pdf file using iTextSharp. The table contains Russian symbols  that are not displayed correctly after cutting (parsing).
I'm doing this:

```
Dim rect_for_page_one As New 
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(MillimetersToPoints(39), MillimetersToPoints(33), MillimetersToPoints(163), MillimetersToPoints(297 - 70))

Dim filter As New RegionTextRenderFilter(rect_for_page_one)

Dim strategyOne As ITextExtractionStrategy 
strategyOne = New FilteredTextRenderListener(New LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter)

Dim output As New String(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PDFReader, 1, strategyOne))
```

[Code screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldpwv.png)

What do I need to do to get correctly displayed Russian symbols?

Comment: Post the code as text, please.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50230947/how-can-i-read-pdf-with-itext/50231200 Unfortunately, the OP doesn't share the PDF, which makes his question unanswerable. Maybe the OP doesn't understand that what you see (on a PDF page) isn't always what you get (from the PDF syntax).